# Force portrait mode on TV through Slimport - Android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, slimport

I just bought an iCAN MyDP Slimport to HDMI adapter for my rooted Nexus 5. It works perfectly fine, but when the phone is in portrait mode, the TV it is connected to makes the image smaller and centers it. Is there any way to force portrait mode on the TV? I have already looked through the TV's settings, there is no option in there.